# Rails, sending json params

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, json

I have to use an API that wants a single param containing a json string :

```
def function
  data = params['data']
  # Do thing with the json string data
  #... More code
end
```

config.rb :

```
match "/thing" => "controller#function", :via => :post
```

I've searched and read the documentation, I can't seems to find a way how to do this. 
I've searched with form_for or form_tag function and this seems not possible.
I've tried both approach using remote => true, but it does not do what I want.

I also tried to do this using jquery $.ajax but it sends parameters in json format and not a json string.

Is there any ways to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try accessing the json object as so

```
data = params[:data].first[0]
```

The [0] was included to read the first element of the json formatted object, assuming it isn't nested within another json object.

Answer (score 0):

I think Rails might automatically be turning the parameter into a hash, since it recognises that it's json. You should be able to turn it back into a string by calling `to_json` on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can still send the data as json string :

- In your jquery ajax setup, set contentType option to "text/html"